# Play silent backround sound without any noise - Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, noise, silent, aiff

I want to play a soundfile when my app is sent to the background or when the phone is sent to sleep mode. 
For this we use `AVFoundation/AVAudioplayer` together with the Backgroundmode Audio. 
This is working fine so far and it does what it should. 
The problem is, even though my soundfile is completly silent (observed with Audacity), I can hear a annoying noise (something like that: https://youtu.be/2P87NS63K94) when the device volume is turned all up. The file is in **.aiff-Format**. 
Is there any way to avoid this noise?

Comment: Where is the code???

Comment: You can try `AVAudioplayer.volume` or switch to AVPlayer and try `AVPlayer.muted` and/or `AVPlayer.volume`